# Particular solution of hypergeometric differential equation with inhomogeneous term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking for the particular solution of an nonhomogeneous second order differential equation. The inhomogeneous term is a function of the form: $\frac{1}{u}$.
I've tried to find the particular solution by the "varying constant technique". That is, if the solution of the homogeneous equation is $C~{}_2F_1(a,b,c,u)$, I look for a particular solution of the form $\tilde{C}(x)~{}_2F_1(a,b,c,u)$. The problem is that this method is not giving me a good result.

Is there any way of trying to get the particular solution by hand (taking into account that the inhomogeneous term is of the form $u^{-1}$)?

Thanks!